# Using fullcalendar/icalendar with script tags

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, icalendar

sorry if this is a super-basic question, but I'd like to use fullcalendar's [icalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/icalendar) package, using script tags.

I see that icalendar isn't on the [list of pre-built bundles](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-globals), but I'm hoping that it's still possible.

My problem is that I'm not sure how to import the plugins (this line `plugins: [DayGridPlugin, iCalendarPlugin],`).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.5.1/main.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ical.js/0.0.3/ical.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.5.1/main.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.5.1/locales-all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/icalendar@5.5.1/main.global.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");
        var today = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];

        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
          initialView: "dayGridMonth",
          initialDate: today,
          headerToolbar: {
            left: "prev,next today",
            center: "title",
            right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay",
          },
          plugins: [DayGridPlugin, iCalendarPlugin],
          events: {
            url: "https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays/england-and-wales.ics",
            format: "ics",
          },
        });

        calendar.render();
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="calendar"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

For context, I use [sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/) as a static site generator for various projects, all of which are hosted using GitHub pages. I've written a sphinx extension which builds a .ics file from the markdown YAML in my static site, and I hope to display the calendar and upcoming events on a page of the site using fullcalendar similar to [this](https://sorse.github.io/) site.

Comment: If you're including via script tags then AFAIK there's no need to use the `plugins` option at all. Just include the files and you're good to go.

Comment: Ooh, thank you that did help! (New error messages now!)

Comment: No worries. Do you need help with those? Another minor thing: `initialDate: today` is redundant - the default value for initialDate is already today's date - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialDate

Answer (score 6):

Finally got this to work.

- First I had to pull the .ics file into my flask backend and serve it from a local URL to circumvent the CORS policy.
- Then I hade to use and updated version of the AJAX iCal library you had.

This code worked for me:

```
<div id='calendar' style="max-height: 80vh;"></div>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.5.1/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ical.js/1.4.0/ical.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.5.1/main.min.js"></script>
// <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.5.1/locales-all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/icalendar@5.5.1/main.global.min.js"></script>

<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: "dayGridMonth",
    headerToolbar: {
      left: "prev,next today",
      center: "title",
      right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay",
    },
    // plugins: [DayGridPlugin, iCalendarPlugin],
    events: {
      url: "/calendar/demo/ics_file",
      // url: "https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays/england-and-wales.ics",
      format: "ics",
    },
  });

  calendar.render();
});
</script>
```

Comment: for multiple ics_files you can just do: 
`eventSources: [ {

      url: "https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays/england-and-wales.ics",

      format: "ics",

      },

      {

      url: "https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays/england-and-wales.ics",

      format: "ics",

      }

    ]`